# javascript null error in doubleclick event

Tags: javascript, events

I get an error in a doubleclick event: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at HTMLDocument.addDeleteListener

for this portion of code...

```
const cardElement = document.querySelector('.card');
function addDeleteListener() {
  cardElement.addEventListener('dblclick', (event) => {
    event.target.remove();
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addDeleteListener);
```

the cards are present in the page, and the selector is properly .class (they are added via this function):

```
function addCard(cardTitle, column) {
  const card = document.createElement('div');
  card.classList.add('card');
  card.innerText = cardTitle;
  column.appendChild(card);
}
```

I cannot seem to work it out :(
ayone can help please?

EDIT:
I have followed some of your advices, for which i thank you all very much, and i have used a different approach...
the new code, now working, is th efollowing:

```
// Function to add a new card to a column
function addCard(cardTitle, column) {
  const card = document.createElement('div');
  card.classList.add('card');
  card.innerText = cardTitle;
  
  column.appendChild(card);

  card.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
    card.remove();
  });
}
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says, cardElement is null.
From the code you shared it's not evident that the .card element is actually in the DOM.

Comment: are you sure the `cardElement` is present at the moment your function is called?

Comment: thats the same i am thinking, maybe add cardElement defintion into the addDeleteListener function

Answer (score 0):

You can define the event listener on some parent container which isn't inserted dynamically, for example, body.

```
document.body.addEventListener('dblclick', (event) => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('card')) {
    event.target.remove();
  }
});
```

This way you:

- Define only one event listener
- Don't need to manage event listeners when dynamically adding new elements

Answer (score 0):

As other noticed, the problem is that `.card` element is not in the dom when `DOMContentLoaded` event fires. The reason may be different: current info about problem is not enough because we don't know when exactly `addCard` function called. Seems like the `const cardElement = document.querySelector('.card');` stays beore that call.. Of before your `column` element insertion into the dom (or even deeper).

In addition, I agree with recommendation to move the listener creation inside `addCard` function.

---

**In addition to** [Anton's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75372646/21156288):

There is two variants of listeners creation:

1. Directly to clickable element;
2. To their static parent (Anton's way);

For example:
A - static parent
B - clickable element (`.card` in your case)
C - any child of B element

---

In the 2 (second) case, listener will broke when you add any `C` to the `B` element because when you click at the `C` element, the `event.target` will be a `C` element.

That means that you must add extra logic to check which `B` element contains that `event.target`. It will require extra dom manipulations (direct or reversed).

In addition, it will be a kind of interruption into `A` wrapper. It is not a problem, when A is special wrapper for cards, but on other case it is not handy.

---

In the 1 (first) case, listener will got click event, no matter how deep the `C` element was.

The `A` element will be untouched.

The listener's lifecycle is more clear: it lives as long as `B` element exist.

In future you will be able to move button into isolated component without breaking changes.

---

The 1 case is a more safe and clear way. Yes, it requires a bit work at B's creation and delete methods, but it's worth it.

In addition, amount of click listeners was never a bit notable problem in my experience.

The second option has the right to life, but you MUST know why and what you are doing.

---

Sorry for my eng xD